# Performance of synchronized getHandlerFor(Type) in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using gson 1.7 and i see that it has a serialized block in toJson()
in class

```
final class ParameterizedTypeHandlerMap<T>{
....
public synchronized T getHandlerFor(Type type) {
....
```

If I'm creating the object per each request it also has a synchronized block in construction.

I have couple questions:

1. Does 2.1 version has the same behaver?
2. Is it safe (in perspective to backward compatibility) to upgrade to 2.1
3. What is best performance package for json?

Comment: Your title is misleading. It implies you have done some performance testing of your own, which from reading your question it would seem you have not. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use gson 2 and it works same as 1.7 for me. You can create an instance of Gson per your Thread if synchronized scare you.

Comment: that what i'm doing now with thread locals. but with tomcat threads it is not so straight forward

Comment: You can create a new instance of Gson in every method where you use it: Gson gson = new Gson(); String json = gson.toJson(someObject); Actualy I always use this pattern for Gson.

Comment: the creation also is very expensive at runtime. It has a synchronized block inside